# Calculate the end date(SLA) from its start date in business hours

Tags: php, laravel, date

I need to calculate end-date/SLA for a given start-date considering the completion-time in minutes within the business hours/days.

For instance :

- start-date = 2019-03-29 15:00:00
- completion-time = 720 (minutes)

Considering 8 working hours per day(9am to 5pm) and weekend on Sunday. The end-date should be 2019-04-01 11:00:00.

So the total hours are 12,

- on 2019-03-29 from 15:00:00 to 17:00:00 (2 hours)
- on 2019-03-30 from 09:00:00 to 17:00:00 (8 hours)
- on 2019-04-01 from 09:00:00 to 11:00:00 (2 hours)

Any help with regards to this would be much appreciated.

So far i can able to get the total working days excluding the weekends but getting exact end time is where i'm struggling.

Thank you.

Update:

```
$bookingDateTime = Carbon::parse('2019-03-29 15:00:00');
$i = 0;
$completion_in_days = (720/60)/8; //converted minutes in no of days
$working_days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

while($i < ($completion_in_days)){
   if(array_search(strtolower($bookingDateTime->englishDayOfWeek), $working_days) !== false){
       $i++; 
   }

   $bookingDateTime->addDay();
}
```

This will give me the end date.

Comment: This sentence is wrong `on 2019-04-01 from 09:00:00 to 10:00:00 (2 hours)
` It should be 11:00:00

Comment: @RahulMeshram thanks buddy, with help of ur's i have figured out the solution.

Comment: Great! If you feel my answer help you sort out your problem, you may accept my answer. Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 1):

Please find the snippet below, I wrote line by line commenting for understanding

```
$endDate     = $startDate     = '2019-03-29 15:00:00';
$officeStart = '09:00:00';
$officeEnd   = '17:00:00';
$totalHours  = 12;
$i           = 1;
$flag        = false;
while ($totalHours > 0) {
    $day = date('D', strtotime($endDate)); // fetching day of week
    if ($day == 'Sun') { // checking if sunday thenskip by adding 1 day to end date
        $endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($endDate . " +1 Day")) . ' ' . $officeStart; // adding one day if sunday
        continue;
    }
    $diff  = strtotime($officeEnd) - strtotime(date("H:i:s", strtotime($endDate))); // getting difference of time of office end date and result end date
    $hours = $diff / (3600); // difference in minutes
    if ($hours > $totalHours) {
        $hours = $totalHours;
        $flag  = true; // to break loop if last loop comes
    } else {
        $totalHours = $totalHours - $hours; // substracting hours from total hours left
    }
    $endDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+$hours Hour", strtotime($endDate))); // adding hours which are substracted
    if (!$flag) {
        $endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($endDate . " +1 Day")) . ' ' . $officeStart; // if not last loop add day to result end date
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
2019-04-01 11:00:00
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/37201acbf0851fafa3679f68dfc5dd07f644deb1).